# main(int argc, char* argv[]) dont understand

Tags: c++, argv

i am trying to understand `int main( argc, char* argv[])` thing.
When i using arguments like `./program  1 bbbbbb`
code:

```
cout<< argv[0] << ' ' << argv[1] << ' '<<  argv[2] << endl;
```

will show: `./program 1 bbbbbb`

but in this case:

```
 cout<< *argv[0] << ' ' << *argv[1] << ' '<<  *argv[2] << endl;
```

will show: `. 1 b`

SO my question is. Is this `char* argv[]` in this situation an array of pointers. And how to get access for strings like `bbbbbbb`.

Ty in advance!

Comment: `argv` is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: `argv[2]` will give you `bbbbbbbb`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this char* argv[] in this situation an array of pointers.

In this case `char* argv[]` is an array of null terminated strings.

Specifically as per §5.1.2.2.1/2 of the C standard:

> If the value of argc is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup.

And:

> If the value of argc is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]` represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]` represent the program parameters.

---

> And how to get access for strings like bbbbbbb.

My suggestion is to do what C++ unfortunately fails to do due to backward compatibility:

```
std::vector<std::string> args(argc);
std::copy(argv, argv + argc, args.begin());
```

and [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42c7ebb295d1bfb6)'s the live demo.

Comment: so why it is (*) placed?

Comment: @user3402584, what do you mean?

Comment: i mean, if argv containts pointers that mean it contains addresses.So in order to check what this pointers are pointing exactly, i should use (*) to get value. So for instance i use *(argv[2]) to get bbbbbb but i get only b.

Comment: @user3402584, `char` arrays are *special* in C. They are intended to be null terminated. Just forget about it and use the two lines code I've posted at the end of this answer and you'll be fine.

Comment: @user3402584: Yes, because `char*` is a pointer to `char`s. So if you dereference the pointer, you get one `char`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> how to get access for strings like bbbbbbb.

You have answered your own question when you say :

> cout<< argv[0] << ' ' << argv[1] << ' '<<  argv[2] << endl;
>   will  show: ./program 1 bbbbbb

`char* argv[]` is an array of pointers and contains the command line arguments (including the excutable name) and `argc` contains the count.
from the example above,

```
argv[0] = ./program
argv[1] = 1
argv[2] = bbbb
```

and

```
argc=3
```

Read this for more clarity: [What does int argc, char *argv[] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)

Comment: ty, i will read it. But if if argv is an array of pointers, shouldnt it contains an various addresses?

Comment: This is what a character pointer is. String declared such a way points to the location where the null terminated string is located. because C++ hides the format specifier in `cout`, if it was `c`, you'd have something like this - `char name[]="siva";  printf("%s\n",name);`. It's just the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

char *[] is read as an array of pointers to char.  Generally, a pointer to char represents a a pointer to a null terminated string.  This is by convention, and when you pass a char * to a routine, like cout, it will print all the characters that the char * points to until it reaches a null.

So, argv[0] points to a memory address starting with the char '.', which has after it more characters until it reaches the null termination: "./program\0".  The cout routine which handles char * will print each character until the null.

When you "dereference" a pointer to char, as in *argv[0], you are asking to return the item that the argv[0] points to.  In this case, * (char *) is saying return to me the character that is being pointed to by the (char *).  The type of this item is a char, aka a *single* character.  The cout routine which prints char (and not char * this time) is instead called, and it prints just that character that is being pointed to.  In the above case, that is a '.'.

Comment: what does null terminated means?that at the end it has '\0' ?

Comment: i am really grateful for help!

Comment: yes, each character in a string is actually stored as a number. 'A' is 41, 'B' is 42, etc.  Null, or '\0' or just 0 is how C strings are terminated, so routines know when to stop (as opposed to Pascal, which would have the length of the string at the beginning).  But you can't just put a 0 at the end of your string, because it would be confused with the character '0' (which has the value of 30, similar to how the 'A' has a value of 41).  So C provides the escape character '\' which you can place in front of the 0 to denote it as the value 0 and not the character 0

Comment: ...The '\0' is added automatically when you use double quotes, e.g. "program".